# Change download-file name ItextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

So I've been using itextsharp to create and download a file to the client. The PDF is created, but is created using the wrong file extension. It is downloaded as "webform1.aspx" But if I change the file extension it is correct. I need to learn how to change the file name when downloading using the memory stream, or a different method if needed. Code below, it is executed via a button on a blank webform.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a Document object
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);

        // Create a new PdfWriter object, specifying the output stream
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

        // Open the Document for writing
        document.Open();
        // Create a new Paragraph object with the text, "Hello, World!"
        var welcomeParagraph = new Paragraph("Hello, World!");

        // Add the Paragraph object to the document
        document.Add(welcomeParagraph);
        document.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
        Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: I thought I had it figured it out...

I changed the response content to Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf" 

This opens it as a page for the client, and shows it as a pdf, but the file type is still aspx. Odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a content-disposition header with filename to Response object

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

Comment: Neat. I'll try this out.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.